# Cluster Sampling problem

Tags: probability, sampling, survey, cluster-sample

I'm using Sharon Lohr's book to self-study, and there is no solution to this problem. I just wanted to make sure I'm computing the values correctly.

Question:

The new candy Green Globules is being test marketed in an area of upstate New York. The market research firm decided to sample 6 cities from the 45 cities in the area and then to sample supermarkets within cities, wanting to know the number of cases of Green Globules sold.

\begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{City} & \mbox{number of supermarkets}  & \mbox{number of cases sold}  \\
\ 1 & 52 & 146, 180, 251, 152, 72, 181, 171, 186, 361, 73 \\
\ 2 & 19& 99, 101, 52, 121 \\
\ 3 & 37  & 199, 179, 98, 63, 126, 87, 62 \\
\ 4 & 39  & 226, 129, 57, 46, 86, 43, 85, 165 \\
\ 5 & 8  & 12, 23 \\
\ 6 & 14 & 87, 43, 59 \end{array}

Obtain the summary statistics for each cluster. Additionally, estimate the total number of cases sold per supermarket, along with the standard error of your estimates.

Attempt:

I will calculate the standard errors later. I would just like to see if I'm doing this part correctly.

Cluster 1: $\bar{y}_1 = 177.3, \hat{t}_1 = M_1*\bar{y}_1 = 9219.6$

Cluster 2: $\bar{y}_2 = 93.25, \hat{t}_2 = M_2*\bar{y}_2 = 1771.75$

Cluster 3: $\bar{y}_3 = 116.29, \hat{t}_3 = M_3*\bar{y}_3 = 4302.57$

Cluster 4: $\bar{y}_4 = 108.625, \hat{t}_4 = M_4*\bar{y}_4 = 4080.375$

Cluster 5: $\bar{y}_5 = 17.5, \hat{t}_5 = M_5*\bar{y}_5 = 140$

Cluster 6: $\bar{y}_6 = 63, \hat{t}_6 = M_6*\bar{y}_6 = 882$

Total number of packages sold: $\frac{N}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^{M_i}\hat{t}_i = 152972.2125$

average number of packages solder per supermarket $ :\hat{y}_{r} = \frac{\Sigma \hat{t}_i}{\Sigma M_i}= \frac{20396.295}{169} = 120.688$

Comment: That's what I get for the total and mean the sensible way using survey software (R `survey`). The SE of the mean is estimated as 20.049.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the answers, here's how to do it in R:

```
> d<-data.frame(
+ sold=c(146,180,251,152,72,181,171,186,361,73,
+        99,101,52,121,
+        199,179,98,63,126,87,62,
+        226,129,57,46,86,43,85,165,
+        12,23,
+        87,43,59),
+ N=rep(c(52,19,37,39,8,14), c(10, 4,7,8,2,3)),
+ city=rep(1:6,c(10,4,7,8,2,3)),
+ Ncities=45,
+ id=1:34)
> 
> with(d, by(sold, city, mean))
city: 1
[1] 177.3
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
city: 2
[1] 93.25
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
city: 3
[1] 116.2857
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
city: 4
[1] 104.625
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
city: 5
[1] 17.5
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
city: 6
[1] 63
> 
> s<-svydesign(~city+id, fpc=~Ncities+N, data=d)
> svymean(~sold,s)
       mean     SE
sold 120.69 20.049
> 
> svytotal(~sold,s)
      total    SE
sold 152972 56781
```

Answer (score 0):

To estimate the total number of cases sold we used this following formula:

$\hat{t}_{unb}=\frac{N}{n} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} \hat{t}_{i}$

$\hat{t}_{unb}=\frac{45}{6} 20396.3$

$\hat{t}_{unb}=152972.088$

```
    For the Standard Error we have:
```

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{aligned}
\\
S \cdot E\left(\hat{t}_{\text {unb }}\right) &=\sqrt{V\left(\hat{t}_{\text {unb }}\right)} \\
&=\sqrt{N^{2}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right) \frac{s_{t}^{2}}{n}+\frac{N}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(1-\frac{m_{i}}{M_{i}}\right) M_{i}^{2} \frac{S_{i}^{2}}{m_{i}}} \\
&=\sqrt{45^{2}\left(1-\frac{6}{45}\right) \frac{10952876.94}{6}+\frac{45}{6}(3257417.93)
}\\
&=\sqrt{3228147139}\\
&=56816.78572\\
\end{aligned}
\end{array}
$$

```
For the average number sold per supermarket
```

$$
\hat{\bar{y}}_{r}=\frac{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} \hat{t}_{i}}{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} M_{i}}= \frac{20396.2964}{169}=120.6881444
$$

```
and its Standard Error
```

$$
S.E(\hat{\bar{y}}_{r})=\sqrt{\hat{V}\left(\hat{\bar{y}}_{r}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\bar{M}^{2}}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right) \frac{s_{r}^{2}}{n}+\frac{1}{n N \bar{M}^{2}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} M_{i}^{2}\left(1-\frac{m_{i}}{M_{i}}\right) \frac{s_{i}^{2}}{m_{i}}}
$$
where
\begin{array}{l}
s_{r}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}}\left(M_{i} \bar{y}_{i}-M_{i} \hat{\bar{y}}_{r}\right)^{2} \\
s_{i}^{2}=\frac{1}{m_{i}-1} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{S}_{i}}\left(y_{i j}-\bar{y}_{i}\right)^{2}
\end{array}

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\left(M_{i} \bar{y}_{i}-M_{i} \bar{y}_{r}\right)^{2} \\
i=1 \mid[(52)(177.3)-(52)(120.6881444)]^{2}=8666055.534 \\
i=2 \mid[(19)(93.25)-(19)(120.6881444)]^{2}=271779.4883 \\
i=3 \mid[(37)(116.29)-(37)(120.6881444)]^{2}=2846875.522 \\
i=4 \mid[(39)(104.625)-(39)(120.6881444)]^{2}=392455.4288 \\
i=5 \mid[(8)(17.5)-(8)(120.6881444)]^{2}=681458.7613 \\
i=6 \mid[(14)(63)-(14)(120.6881444)]^{2}=652272.7128
\end{array}
$$
$$
\sum\left(M_{i} {\bar{y}}_{i}-M_{i} \hat{\bar{y}}_{r}\right)^{2}=13510897.45
$$

\begin{array}{l}
s_{r}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}}\left(M_{i} \bar{y}_{i}-M_{i} \hat{\bar{y}}_{r}\right)^{2}\\
s_{r}^{2}=\frac{1}{5}(13510897.45)\\
\end{array}

$$
\begin{array}{l}
S.E(\hat{\bar{y}}_{r})=\sqrt{\hat{V}\left(\hat{\bar{y}}_{r}\right)}\\
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\bar{M}^{2}}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right) \frac{s_{r}^{2}}{n}+\frac{1}{n N \bar{M}^{2}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} M_{i}^{2}\left(1-\frac{m_{i}}{M_{i}}\right) \frac{s_{i}^{2}}{m_{i}}}\\
=\sqrt{\frac{1}{793.3611111}\left(1-\frac{6}{45}\right) \frac{2702179.49}{6}+\frac{1}{(6) (45)(793.3611111)} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} M_{i}^{2}\left(1-\frac{m_{i}}{M_{i}}\right) \frac{s_{i}^{2}}{m_{i}}}\\
=23.55950159\\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Number of }\\
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\text { City } & \text { Supermarkets } & \text { Number of Cases Sold } & t_{i} & \hat{t}_{i} & y_{i U} & \text { S.E } y_{i U} \\
\hline & & & & & & \\
1 & 52 & 146,180,251,152,72,181,171,361,73,186 & 1773 & 9219.6 & 177.3 & 35.1189 \\
2 & 19 & 99,101,52,121 & 373 & 1771.75 & 93.25 & 11.9368 \\
3 & 37 & 199,179,98,63,126,87,62 & 814 & 4302.5714 & 116.29 & 22.2657 \\
4 & 39 & 226,129,57,46,86,43,85,165 & 837 & 4080.357 & 104.625 & 277232 \\
5 & 8 & 12,23 & 35 & 140 & 17.5 & 2.9399 \\
6 & 14 & 87,43,59 & 189 & 882 & 63 & 3.6056
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
M_{i} & m_{i} & s_{i}^{2} & t_{i} & \bar{y}_{i} & \hat{t}_{i} & \left(1-\frac{m_{i}}{M_{i}}\right) M_{i}^{2} \frac{S_{i}^{2}}{m_{i}} & \left(\hat{t}_{i}-\frac{\hat{t}_{u n b}}{N}\right)^{2} \\
\hline & & & & & & \\
52 & 10 & 6988.9 & 1773 & 177.3 & 9219.6 & 1526375.76 & 33874963.95 \\
19 & 4 & 854.916667 & 373 & 93.25 & 1771.75 & 601912.8125 & 2649178.549 \\
37 & 7 & 2974.57145 & 814 & 116.29 & 4302.5714 & 47168.0442 & 815755.1867 \\
39 & 8 & 4172.267857 & 837 & 104.625 & 4080.367 & 630533.9799 & 463730.0377 \\
8 & 2 & 60.5 & 35 & 17.5 & 140 & 1452 & 10623556.25 \\
14 &3 & 496 & 189 & 63 & 882 & 25461.3333 & 6337200.722
\end{array}\\
\text { Total: }
\end{array}
$$

```
    Minor Solution for the table
    
            for:
```

$s_{i}^{2}=\frac{1}{m-1} \sum\left(y_{i j}-\bar{y}_{i}\right)^{2}$

$s_{1}^{2}=\frac{1}{9}(62900.1)=6988.9$
$s_{2}^{2}=\frac{1}{3}(2564.75)=854.916667$
$s_{3}^{2}=\frac{1}{6}(17847.4287)=2974.57145$
$s_{4}^{2}=\frac{1}{7}(29205.875)=4172.267857$
$s^{2}=\frac{1}{1}(60.5)=60.5$
$s^{2}_{6}=\frac{1}{2}\left(99^{2}\right)=496 .$

```
        for:
```

$\left(1-\frac{m_{i}}{M_{i}}\right) M_{i}^{2} \frac{S_{i}^{2}}{m_{i}}$

$\left(1-\frac{10}{52}\right)\left(52^{2}\right) \frac{(6988.9)}{10}=1526375.76$
$\left(1-\frac{4}{19}\right)\left(19^{2}\right) \frac{854.916667}{9}=601912.8125$
$\left(1-\frac{7}{37}\right)\left(37^{2}\right) \frac{2974.57145}{7}=471682.0442$
$\left(1-\frac{8}{39}\right)\left(39^{2}\right)\left(\frac{4172.267857}{8}\right)=630533.9799$
$\left(1-\frac{3}{14}\right)\left(14^{2}\right)\left(\frac{496}{3}\right)=25461.3333$
$\left(1-\frac{2}{8}\right)\left(8^{2}\right)\left(\frac{60.5}{2}\right)=1452$

```
    for:
```

$s_{t}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum\left(\hat{t}_{i}-\frac{\hat{t}_{u n b}}{N}\right)^{2}$
$s_{t}^{2}=\frac{1}{5}(54764384.7)$
$s_{t}^{2}=10952876.94$

actually, I'm not sure too. can someone verify also?

Comment: There's no way that could be the standard error of the mean; it's much too big.